# Is there currently any way for two ethernet endpoints to discover how many switches or routes are between them?

Tags: c

Suppose you have 2 network switches cascaded or linked together and three hosts.
Suppose two hosts were on the same switch (host A & B), and the third (host C) was on the other switch.

Is it possible to programatically detect that Host A and B are on the same switch and host C is one hop away from A & B?  I know it can be done with routers, but what about switches?

If I can be done, is there any code available in C for me to detect that?

Comment: From 'intuition' I'd have said it's possible with switches and not with routers (at least not any). But if you know its possible with routers per se, I'd assume it's surely also possible with switches.

Comment: So I guess collecting the results of traceroute is not what you want?

Comment: With switches it is not possible, since they don't modify packet and it's possible to send packet with TTL=1 through switch, so you can't calculate number of switches your packet went through.

Comment: Tudor, no because a traceroute shows routes not switch equipment.

Comment: @MattH: I doubt this can be done at layer 2, since AFAIK there's no `time to live`-type field in the Ethernet header.

Comment: Ok.  I am satisfied that currently, the answer to this is NO.

Answer (score 0):

Directly - no, but there are some ways. Note that some of these may be counted as illegal.

- Most obvious and simple, you may measure latency, see http://www.ruggedcom.com/pdfs/application_notes/latency_on_a_switched_ethernet_network.pdf. You may connect your machines directly first and measure their own latencies (and you may need some kernel tweaks to minimize and/or stabilize it), then through a switch your own, then measure latency through the network and compare the values.
- The method above may be enhanced with sending huge traffic between two hosts and see how it affects measurements from other hosts
- You may overflow CAM table on a switch by sending frames from random source MAC addresses which will effectively turn it into a hub, which other hosts connected to it will notice by getting traffic not directed to them. This way it's pretty easy to know that two hosts are on the same switch
- Doing the latter for multiple chained switches and/or from multiple machines will get you the number of L2 hops between them
- See http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-02/bh-us-02-convery-switches.pdf, or google "layer 2 security".

Comment: For me, the answer in practical terms is NO.  The methods you suggest as "illegal" are not practical for what I am wanting.  latency/throughput will be my best guess.